# Nuget hozed, or package broken?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3 on a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro, and am trying to install the TensorFlowSharp package. Running VS as administrator, new console application (nothing in it yet), I get the errors below when installing. How do I isolate if this is an issue with NuGet itself or with the package I am trying to install? I have uninstalled/reinstalled NuGet, but the error is the same:

```
PM> Install-Package TensorFlowSharp
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication6', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0'
Adding package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' to folder 'C:\Users\roger\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\packages'
Added package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' to folder 'C:\Users\roger\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' does not exist in project 'ConsoleApplication6'
Removing package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' from folder 'C:\Users\roger\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\packages'
Removed package 'TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0' from folder 'C:\Users\roger\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\packages'
Install-Package : The attribute "CopyToOutputDirectory" in element <None> is unrecognized.  C:\Users\roger\documents\visual studio 
2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\packages\TensorFlowSharp.0.96.0\build\TensorFlowSharp.targets
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package TensorFlowSharp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Solved >

(facepalm) Right click > properties on vs 2015 projects folder and unchecked the read-only flag. Seriously? VS, running as admin did not matter.Nice waste of 60 minutes troubleshooting.

Comment: well... nuget installed it, but now I cannot build. When I rebuild, I get no errors, one project failed. When I close reopen visual stuido, I get " The Attribute "CopyToOutputDirectory" in element <None> is unrecognized.

Comment: It has a dependency on System.ValueTuple.  Miguel has all the latest toys, VS2017 required.

Comment: System.ValueTuple works fine in VS2015, so I still don't see why TensorFlowSharp doesn't work in VS2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nuget hozed, or package broken?

I have installed the TensorFlowSharp package on my machine with Visual Studio 2015, and got the same error:

> The attribute "CopyToOutputDirectory" in element  is
>   unrecognized.

But when I installed it on the Visual Studio 2017, it installed successfully without any error. Then I build the project, it works fine.

Besides, I have noticed that this packaged was create at Sunday, May 21, 2017 (5/21/2017), so this package may created with Visual Studio 2017 and the author would not notice backward compatibility.

To resolve this issue we need to contact the package owners for assistance or you can **use the Visual Studio 2017**.

Comment: I'll have to play and see. I am using 2015 because the CUDA libraries don't seem to like 2017: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#axzz4l8MXDuIW

Answer (score 0):

Roger is correct. Right click on the projects folder and make sure Read Only is not checked. That should solve the issue atleast in VS2015

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423409)